# Dynamicaly view with different content

Tags: ios, uiview, ios-autolayout

I have got UIView with UIImageView + UILabels + UITextView.

I don't know how to make this views in UIScrollView, that will show corectly on horizontal and portrait?

Any sugestion?

I thought about uitableview with many cells as UIImageView and Labels, but I need use uiTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths For image and text.

Any sugestions or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Tableview might be a better solution or just simply try to use autoLayout with the elements you want. Working in scrollview with autoLayout might be tricky on some occasions but these seem good solutions to me.

Answer (score 0):

define the size and position of contentView inside scroll view

even if you set all constraint from your contentView to scroll view (top, right, bottom, left) to some constant values, the size of your contentView is not defined!!! that is very common mistake ...

set height and width of the contentView, that is all (without any relation to scroll view). like width = 5000, height = 5000. why not? the scroll view will be just like a small window to big room behind. it is the only reason why to use a scroll view, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit below link:

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Hope it will help solving your issue.